# Cannot read JSON with Pandas a file encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian

Tags: json, pandas, utf-8, ucs2

```
with open(filename+'.json') as json_file:
data=pd.io.json.read_json(json_file,encoding='utf_16_be')
```

I tried multiple options for encoding but it fails. It returns empty object. I can convert only when save my file in Notepad++ as UTF8 without BOM. I open it as normally with default encoding:

```
with open(filename+'.json') as json_file:
data=pd.io.json.read_json(json_file)
```

Default encoding of the file is UTC-2 Little Endian. How to read json with this encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow `import pandas as pd; help (pd.io.json.read_json)`. The following (partially commented) code snippet could help:

```
filename = r"D:\PShell\DataFiles\61571258" # my test case

import pandas as pd

filepath = filename + ".json"

# define encoding while opening a file 
with open(filepath, encoding='utf-16') as f:
    data = pd.io.json.read_json(f)

# or open file in binary mode and decode while converting to pandas object
with open(filepath, mode='rb') as f:
    atad = pd.io.json.read_json(f, encoding='utf-16')

# ensure that both above methods are equivalent
print((data == atad).values)
```

**Output**: `.\SO\69537408.py`

> [[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]]